# Proxy entire network traffic from computer not only from browser

Tags: vpn, internet, proxy

What is the best way to proxy entire network traffic (so all applications and browsers) from computer toward some proxy server, so my IP address stays hidden on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

A more suitable solution to hide all your network traffic on one device would be a VPN. There are plenty of providers out there such as ExpressVPN. Simple to install, setup and use. All your traffic would go over the VPN to the internet, it's more secure and faster too unless your proxy can cache, but that is another and more complex discussion. Most people use a proxy for other reasons other than hiding their IP. A VPN will hide your public IP address and only the exit point will be visible. If your VPN provider allows more than one user behind the VPN (NAT) and does not keep or record logs, you will be fine.